# Why does my query return a SQL Syntax Error while trying to create my table - MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I've been trying to create a table, and I can't figure out what's wrong with the syntax. Created other tables just fine. If you could enlighten me, I'd truly appreciate it!

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_ytvideos`(    `ID` VARCHAR NOT NULL,    `videoTitle` VARCHAR NULL,    `videoOwner` VARCHAR NULL,    PRIMARY KEY(`ID`))
```

Mysql response:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
>       `videoTitle` VARCHAR NULL,
>       `videoOwner` VARCHAR NULL,
>       P' at line 2

Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: I don't know much (anything) about MariaDB so take this with a grain of salt, but when I put your code into https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and ran under MySQL it failed until I added lengths for the varchar columns

Comment: Problem was the varchar. had to insert a length. CREATE TABLE wp_ytvideos(
    ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    videoTitle VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    videoOwner VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

Comment: Yes, that is correct @MikeTheLiar, thanks for taking the time to test it out!

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR columns need a length specified at creation.

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_ytvideos` (`ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
             `videoTitle` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
             `videoOwner` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY(`ID`))
```